# Discretizing the PID equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am discretizing the PID equation so we have this equation

[image]

Now if we separate the integral term we get

[image]

Applying backward euler method

[image]

Now as we already have a differentiation , by applying backward euler method
[image]

and the end equation is something like this

[image]

I just want to ask if I did something mathematically wrong or did I miss a step ?

P.S I am new to this forum so I just added my solution I solved in a word file

Comment: Rather than using images please learn Mathjax; then you can label your formulae making it much easier for people to comment on what you have done.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I am sorry for the rush , I am new to math stack exchange actually so had never used it before , I will try to improve it

Comment: How do you define $e(t)$? and is there a typo on the 3rd formula line down with the extra $dt$?

Comment: @JamesArathoon $e(t)$ is basically the current error which is defined as `error = setpoint - Processvalue` which is the input to our PID controller

Comment: @JamesArathoon you are right $dt$ is a typo

Comment: This seems ok. To implement the measured input/process value may need a low pass filter applied to remove unwanted high frequency noise content that may upset the differential term. Also in a real world implementation thought often needs to be given to potential hardware failures which cause the integral term to runaway in the control algorithm. Often some sort of integral limit or desaturation algorithm is applied to avoid this problem.